# Set Image To Span Entire Header Width

Tags: image, ms-access, header, report

In an access report I have an image that is the only thing in the header.  When I preview the report it is centered in the header.  If I try to stretch teh image further out I get a message saying I have extended the page width.  How can I auto-set this image to span the page width?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set ***Picture Alignment*** to `Top Left`
Set ***Picture Size Mode*** to `Stretch Horizontal`

See below screenshot
[image]